# How to select current date in Hive SQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

How do we get the current system date in Hive? In MySQL we have select now(), can any one please help me to get the query results. I am very new to Hive, is there a proper documentation for Hive that gives the details information about the pseudo columns, and built-in functions.

Answer (score 93):

According to the [LanguageManual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions), you can use `unix_timestamp()` to get the "current time stamp using the default time zone." If you need to convert that to something more human-readable, you can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, works perfectly, should be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: You can get complete information from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Note that the current documentation entry (LanguageManual, 2019-03-20) for unix_timestamp() says "this has been deprecated since 2.0 in favour of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP constant."

Answer (score 56):

Yes... I am using Hue 3.7.0 - The Hadoop UI and to get current date/time information we can use below commands in Hive:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()); --/Selecting Current Time stamp/

SELECT CURRENT_DATE; --/Selecting Current Date/

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; --/Selecting Current Time stamp/
```

However, in Impala you will find that only below command is working to get date/time details:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()); --/Selecting Current Timestamp /
```

Hope it resolves your query :)

Answer (score 23):

The functions `current_date` and `current_timestamp` are now available in Hive 1.2.0 and higher, which makes the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: The  Hive 1.2 in the distribution Cloudera  doesn't contains the function current_date. However it contains the function unix_timestamp()

Answer (score 21):

To fetch only current date excluding time stamp:

in lower versions, looks like hive CURRENT_DATE is not available, hence you can use (it worked for me on Hive 0.14)

```
select TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()));
```

In higher versions say hive 2.0, you can use :

```
select CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: just to mention that `current_date`is avialalble starting from Hive 1.2.0 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 11):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

current_date - current date

`yyyyMMdd` - my systems current date format;

`yyyy-MM-dd` - if you wish to change the format to a diff one.

Comment: This query worked for me: select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyyMMddHHMMSS');

Answer (score 8):

To extract the year from current date

```
SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

**IBM Netezza**

```
extract(year from now())
```

**HIVE**

```
SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: has something changed since 2013? What version do you use now? Specify if something has changed.